# Entity Framework query ToString won't produce SQL query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

Through my research I've discovered that, since at least EF 4.1, the .ToString() method on an EF query will return the SQL to be run. Indeed, this very frequently works for me, using Entity Framework 5 and 6.

However, occasionally I call this method and get the runtime type of the query object.
Here is my specific example:

```
Entity input = ...;
IQueryable<Entity> query = dbContext.SetOfEntity.Where(e => e.Prop == input.Prop);
```

More specifically, I'm setting a breakpoint in VS2013 and hovering over the query object, and seeing`System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<Namespace.Entity>` instead of the SQL to run that query. Interestingly enough, if I hover over the DBSet property (`dbContext.SetOfEntity`), I *do* see the basic select SQL for the associated table. It's only when I filter the results that I lose the SQL.

Obviously, this is a pretty simple query and I could work out the SQL for myself, but this problem has happened on more complex queries, and it would be nice to be able to debug the SQL being sent to the server without running a database trace.

**Some background**

A while back, I was using EF5 and the ToString() seemed to work. Shortly before switching to EF6, it seemed that **none** of the queries showed me SQL, but after switching to EF6, it went back to the correct behavior.
Additionally, whenever I hover over IQueryable queries and try to use the IDE's "Results View" feature, it tells me "Children could not be evaluated". This may be a separate issue, but I figure I'd include it in case it had a common cause.

Comment: In EF6, you can add logging to [`DbContext.Database.Log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.log%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) by assigning correct delegate. All executed SQL will be logged, including inserts, updates etc.

Comment: I've had the same problem in the past.  In my case it was because I was accidentally doing LINQ-to-objects queries on top of the initial `SELECT *` query, so as it was LINQ-to-objects the actual object for the query was different (and SQL-free), so it wasn't there.  Eventually I found out what I was doing wrong and fixed my query.  It might be worth you reviewing your problematic queries and/or what types they are being assigned as to check you aren't accidentally doing parts of the query client-side.

Comment: @martin_costello I'm actually looking at a query nearly identical to the one in the question (just with domain-specific names for `Entity` and `Prop`) and having this problem. Since `Where` is an IQueryable function and it's of type `DbQuery`, I'm not sure if there's any way it could be Linq-to-objects.

Comment: @EnvisionAndDevelop OK fair enough, it was just a thought.  Maybe double-check the type of your `SetOfEntity` property is correctly returning a 'DbSet<T>` and not something else?  I've also had odd problems before when a property hasn't been virtual so EF hasn't been able to correctly setup lazy loading features.

Comment: @martin_costello No hostilities intended, I just wanted to clarify for other readers that this doesn't seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not need the SQL BEFORE it is executed against the DB you can do the following:

```
dbContext.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

This would print the SQL (and some additional data) to the debug output.
See the following link for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-DE/data/dn469464

Also check, as martin_costello suggested, that you are not querying the DB before you try to get the SQL via `ToString()`. It happened to me too, that I already got objects, because of using `IEnumerable<>` "to early" (instead if `IQueryable<>`) and so got way to many entities from the DB and did some filtering "in code" instead of "in SQL"...

Comment: This does address my concern about retrieving the SQL that has been run, although I would prefer one that fixes the problem rather than its symptom.
Unfortunately we already use Database.Log for a special error handling function, so this would also not be much easier than simply running a trace.
I'll wait a little while longer for more answers before I accept this one.